# Find out latest version

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to get the logic to find out latest versions among two version numbers
for e.g for blackberry mobile OS, it will return the version number like this '6.0.1'. Some other os might return 6.1 only or 6.1.2.4 something like that. I wish to get logic in C# to find the latest version of the provided version numbers.

for e.g.
i. Find the latest of the below

```
1. 5.2.4 
2. 6.1.6
```

ii.

```
1. 6.1.4.6
2. 1.8.4.2
```

Comment: Can't you just remove the '.', convert them to integers then do an is greater than?

Comment: Providing they have the same number of dots (which I'd think they should)

Comment: I need some generalized logic

Comment: @ThePower no, because then 5.10.2.1 would be seen as greater than 6.0.0.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) class:

```
static Version Max(Version x, Version y)
{
    if (x >= y)
        return x;
    return y;
}
```

If you have the versions as strings, you can parse them with [`Version.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.parse.aspx).